# Making my computer work as a WiFi access point without using ICS

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ics

So ... the easiest way to create a WiFi network on Windows 7 is using ICS.
However, I'd like to create a simple WiFi network to make my computer work as a router. In Linux (generically, but I've done this in Ubuntu 8.10 or so, with atheros) you can set your WiFi card into "router" mode.

Why do **I** want to do this?
I can't make my Kindle connect to my PC otherwise. It needs a WiFi network, and I have only got an ad hoc network in my home. (Note: I'm using the latest, 3.2.1 firmware on the Kindle.)

My WiFi card: **Intel 5100 AGN 1x2 MC Wireless WiFi Adapter (Lenovo - MOW2)**
Host OS: **Windows 7 x64 SP1 - Professional**

I don't mind a solution that costs, except for buying a router.

Comment: "work as a Wifi AP" would be a more common term

Comment: I'll edit the question, ty!

Comment: Are you trying to turn your computer into an access point or a router? For an access point, just set your WiFi card into AP mode, if it supports it. And ICS doesn't make a WiFi network -- it provides Internet sharing over any type of existing network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) should do what you want!

[image]

Personally, I would most likely use ICS, that being said, obviously this actually requires infrastructure or an ad-hoc network. Using this program allows you to create a virtual router.

Comment: Hmm nice. I have found Connectify also after a long Google trip. Which one should I use? :)

Comment: @Shiki They both use the same APIs inside Windows - use whichever one you are most comfortable with... I wa also trying to look for connectify (I have used both in the past) but I couldn't think of its name! I think connectify gives a few more options, especially around security, but, both work very well.